# How to add multiple search values and multiple replacement values in ReplaceText Processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I wanted to modify the content of flow files in such a way that some parts of original content should be replaced with my own string values in whole content. Attached is my sample flow file in Json format. I wanted to replace the field names like "bulletinGroupName","bulletinSourceName" etc with my own values like "ProcessorGroupName", "Processor Name" respectively. I am trying to use ReplaceText Processor, but not able to get the desired result. Attached is my some part of nifi flow. Also, I wanted to know how to get the new lines in same flow file. I wanted to write the modified content of flow file to another file(text format is also fine)with new lines between each array element of Json file. Example expected output file and configured processor are also attached. Have a look. Appreciate your help.

[Sample Flow File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoFVz.png)[Expected Output File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nJQI.png)[Nifi Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6VAN.png)[Processor Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJWCs.png)